Brain injury related tags
I asked a question in regards to Hemispatial Neglect, an acquired brain injury. I noticed we don't have any related tags yet as best I could tell.
Should these be generically tagged as brain-injury or should they be specified as acquired-brain-injury, traumatic-brain-injury ect? 
Since we don't currently have many questions relating to brain injuries it may not be worth splitting out into traumatic/non-traumatic brain injury, and brain injury is generally assumed to be acquired brain injury (otherwise it's a defect, not an injury).

I'll just suggest a generic brain-injury tag and we can watch how it grows. As a small site it's probably best to have an easy to find and apply tag.

neurotrauma is a nice generic term for everything injury related (cf. Journal of Neurotrauma).  I don't know how much we'd get into spinal cord injury here, but it's possible, and the tag would cover that, too.
congential-anomaly would work for all non-acquired conditions, but is more generic.

Congenital anomaly is a perfect fit for non-acquired "damage".
